# Django models not displaying in html tempate

Tags: django

Here is the models I am trying to pass into the html template. It is a model that adds on to the user profile. Every with the models is working correctly and I have already created an object with the model.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    # ----- Model Choices -----
    STATE_CHOICES = (('AL', 'Alabama'), ('AK', 'Alaska'), ('AS', 'American Samoa'), ('AZ', 'Arizona'), ('AR', 'Arkansas'), ('AA', 'Armed Forces Americas'), ('AE', 'Armed Forces Europe'), ('AP', 'Armed Forces Pacific'), ('CA', 'California'), ('CO', 'Colorado'), ('CT', 'Connecticut'), ('DE', 'Delaware'), ('DC', 'District of Columbia'), ('FL', 'Florida'), ('GA', 'Georgia'), ('GU', 'Guam'), ('HI', 'Hawaii'), ('ID', 'Idaho'), ('IL', 'Illinois'), ('IN', 'Indiana'), ('IA', 'Iowa'), ('KS', 'Kansas'), ('KY', 'Kentucky'), ('LA', 'Louisiana'), ('ME', 'Maine'), ('MD', 'Maryland'), ('MA', 'Massachusetts'), ('MI', 'Michigan'), ('MN', 'Minnesota'), ('MS', 'Mississippi'), ('MO', 'Missouri'), ('MT', 'Montana'), ('NE', 'Nebraska'), ('NV', 'Nevada'), ('NH', 'New Hampshire'), ('NJ', 'New Jersey'), ('NM', 'New Mexico'), ('NY', 'New York'), ('NC', 'North Carolina'), ('ND', 'North Dakota'), ('MP', 'Northern Mariana Islands'), ('OH', 'Ohio'), ('OK', 'Oklahoma'), ('OR', 'Oregon'), ('PA', 'Pennsylvania'), ('PR', 'Puerto Rico'), ('RI', 'Rhode Island'), ('SC', 'South Carolina'), ('SD', 'South Dakota'), ('TN', 'Tennessee'), ('TX', 'Texas'), ('UT', 'Utah'), ('VT', 'Vermont'), ('VI', 'Virgin Islands'), ('VA', 'Virginia'), ('WA', 'Washington'), ('WV', 'West Virginia'), ('WI', 'Wisconsin'), ('WY', 'Wyoming'))
    FRESHMAN = 'FR'
    SOPHOMORE = 'SO'
    JUNIOR = 'JR'
    SENIOR = 'SR'
    YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = (
        (FRESHMAN, 'Freshman'),
        (SOPHOMORE, 'Sophomore'),
        (JUNIOR, 'Junior'),
        (SENIOR, 'Senior'),
    )
    HIGH_SCHOOL = 'High School'
    COLLEGE = 'College'
    SCHOOL_TYPE = (
        (HIGH_SCHOOL, 'High School'),
        (COLLEGE, 'College')
    )
    # ----- Model Fields -----
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=250, choices=STATE_CHOICES, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True)
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True)
    school_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=SCHOOL_TYPE ,blank=True)
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES, blank=True)
    skill_one = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    skill_two = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Here is my view, I made sure everything is imported correctly.

```
@login_required
def tutors(request):
all_profiles = Profile.objects.all()
return render(request, 'userhome/tutors.html', {'all_profiles':all_profiles})
```

This is the html templates where I am looping through the objects in sqlite database.

```
    {% extends 'userhome/base.html' %}

{% block body %}
<div class='tutors-container'>
    {% for profile in all_profiles %}
        {{ profile.first_name }}
        {{ profile.last_name }}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

When I run the code the profile objects does not display on the html template, even though I have an object created that is stored in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Your create user profile doesn’t set the first_name or last_name on the profile

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        profile = Profile.objects.create(
            user=instance,  
            first_name=instance.first_name, 
            last_name=instance.first_name
        )
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Do I have to set the all of the rows in the model in the create_user_profile function?

Comment: This is the wrong approach. The Profile model shouldn't duplicate those fields at all; the template should access them via the user.

Comment: @DanielRoseman It certainly isn’t the right way of doing it, I was just pointing out the part they missed

Comment: @M.Pottratz I would assume you have some way of the user editing their profile as the other fields wouldn’t be on the user model anyway, so set up a profile form and view if you haven’t already got that